I have created all the method of app life cycle and a Toast message inside to,only the onResume() and onStop() Toast is appearing
I am learning app life cycle.I have created methods of app life cycle and a toast message inside to know when the methods are called.I dont know what has gone wrong.
package com.example.layout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate() is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStart() is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onResume() is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onPause() is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStop() is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRestart() is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy() is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

I have tried understanding the problem by running one method at a time.Like I commented all the method except the onCreate(),They onCreate toast message appeared but when i uncommented the onStart(),the onStart() toast appeared whereas onCreate() Toast didnt.

Use Log instead of Toast and visualize the output in LogCat..

Toast is not a reliable debugging/logging method. See @SpiritCrusher s comment.
